# iOS: Voice to text for a search box

Tags: ios, voice-recognition

What is the best way to accomplish voice to text for a search box? I don't know if there is a good api to help accomplish this. Or is it better to use the built in voice to text that Apple gave us? I am hoping to get this working for older Iphone devices.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get something done *in spite of* Apple's OS restrictions is never a good way to approach things in a maintainable way. There is probably a library out there to do voice-to-text, but the built-in one is device restricted because voice-to-text requires some heavy lifting.